# Linux cifs share allow different user than mounted/masked uid to do cp -p

Tags: linux, network-attached-storage, cifs

I have a specific linux-server that runs several batch jobs at night creating files and copying them to various locations on a NAS, previously mounted with NFS but as of lately with CIFS.

The reason for this being our new NAS does not support sharing a filesystem as both nfs and cifs simultaneously (multi-protocol share) in a way that suits us. So I instead mounted the share as a cifs share, with windows credentials in .smbcredentials file.

This share is as old as time it self and it's accessed by many a system (Linux servers and Windows servers). However they all have their own servers, so when I mount the share as cifs on one of those Linux-servers I can just set/mask the uid and gid in the fstab to their respective service user and all is fine and dandy.

On the server that I first mentioned however there are several system running on the same server as their own individual users. So I need to mask the uid/gid in fstab to look like one user, but still allow the others to do stuff.

This mostly works but not cp -p, preserve the time stamps of files. This I just cannot seem to get working.

Any tips I could try? I have of course googled my *ss off, trying anything from here to the moon...

Also I am of course trying to get the dev teams to move to their own servers but that's not gonna happen any time soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have, at times, needed to use posix extended attributes (ACLs) to give multiple users access to a set of files through a CIFS server that does not authenticate to our central directory service.  So for example you could try using setfacl on the SMB server, to map permissions onto files/folders, that will give the correct access to users on the Linux client(s).  If you try this, don't forget to set the default ACL, too (this mimics the idea of inheritance on CIFS, although not perfectly).

If the users start twiddling the permissions themselves, it can get messy in a hurry.  But I think your problem can probably be solved this way.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the best solution for my specific problem! :-)